# Web Design with HTML 5

Tags: html, web

I am new to web design and I want to create a webpage from scratch. I am using Notepad++ to write my HTML, and am wondering how to make it "HTML 5". I don't really understand how to define it as HTML 5 or how to save it in that format. Is it just how you write the code out that makes it HTML 5? Thank you

Comment: You may get down voted for this question because this is not really a question for SO. Most people will tell you to google this question if your looking for a simple definition to what HTML 5 is.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

Comment: [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: if you understand german, here is a nice guy from Opera, talking about what is actually called html-5 and browserlove not browserwar    http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13FuU7eNGG0

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice place to start: [html5bones.com](http://html5bones.com) ;-)

The files contain many comments to help you learn how to use some of the more basic elements.

(It's my site - but I thought that you might find it useful)

Comment: It would be nice to explicitly state that you are the author of this website ;)

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has the same format(.html), and to make it a html5 document add this doctype-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

HTML5 is just html 4 with some new tags.
Learn html5 [here](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The doctype is the first step to make a HTML5 file.

Write `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the very beginning of the file.

HTML 5 uses most of the same codes that HTML 4 does but HTML 5 also have alot of new codes like `<audio>` `<video>` `<canvas>` and easyer ways to write code like for example `<meta charset="utf-8">` to indicate the encoding of the file.

Here is a basic HTML 5 file you can use to get started.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>HTML 5 file</title>

</head>

<body>

   Write something here

</body>

</html>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/ is the place you can read all the details. Its not so easy to understand but give it a go. Once you start coding and need to know how to use a specific tag or attribut you go to that link and look it up and get all the details.

Also you could use places like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ and http://dev.opera.com/ they have working working examples and good place to get ideas of what to make.

Comment: Thank you for all the wonderful replies! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Start your HTML5 coding with some frameworks.

http://html5boilerplate.com/ 
http://www.initializr.com/

These have predefined methods, css, javascripts and Jquery. It helps to the cross browser compatibility also.

Notepad++ is good for the development. Moreover you Dreamweaver CS6 or Titanium Studio etc..It will help at the time of your coding. Will get lot of shortcuts.

HTML5 has lot of new tags, features and all. You have to refer for that. http://www.html5rocks.com/ and http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp are the good website for the reference.

expect we will get more from other friends... :)